# Accessing values from a character matrix to open relevant data frames available in the workspace

Tags: r

I have a character matrix two column matrix (named it as "j") whose dimension is 66 x 2, each of the elements in the character matrix contains the names of data frames which is available in the current workspace. I would want to write a R script which reads the Character Matrix ("j"), pick's up the data frame names from it, and then reads the data frame available in the workspace.